# How many subgraphs can be formed from a graph having $e$ sides?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification

A couple of days ago I was asked this question, and with no prior experience of Graph Theory I attempted to come up with a solution ,

$H(\alpha, \beta)$ is a subgraph of $G(V, E)$ if and only if $\alpha \subseteq V$ and $\beta \subseteq E$.

$e$ as the edge count of graph $G$ represents the cardinality of the edge set of $G$, i.e. $E$.

Since a graph must have at least one vertex but *can* contain $0$ edges, $\phi$ can represent an edge set as well. Hence, the total number of subgraphs of $G$ is the cardinality of $P(E)$ where $P$ is the power set of a given set.

$$|P(E)| = 2^e$$
$$\therefore \text{the number of subgraphs is } 2^e$$

---

If this solution is not correct, please let me know of any pointers or where in the concept I went wrong here, I'm soon going to start Graph Theory and I haven't found any solution to this current problem anywhere (Web search and Discrete mathematics and its applications by Rosen) yet.

Comment: Under the definition you gave, a graph with two vertices and one edge will have 5 "subgraphs", not the $2^1=2$ that you claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't right, you are effectively choosing subgraphs by choosing which edges to include. But that doesn't say which vertices you are including in each subgraph (apart from the ones attached to the chosen edges). E.g. if an edge is not chosen, do we include the 2 vertices joined by that edge, perhaps just one of them, or perhaps neither? Also, it depends on whether or not the subgraphs have to "look" different from one another (isomorphically distinct). E.g. if you have a graph on 3 vertices with 3 edges (a triangle) there are 3 ways to make a subgraph with 2 vertices and 1 edge. But they are all the same graph, so should we count them as distinct subgraphs? The job of counting numbers of graphs with a certain property is generally a hard one. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. I'll be honest, I did think of what you mentioned here (partly) .. thanks for clarifying. This definitely helps. Since this answer corresponds to what I asked, I'll select this as an answer now :)