# How many different subgraphs are there in a given graph with V vertices and E edges?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I was studying graphs from Algorithms in C++, Part 5: Graph Algorithms : Sedgewick and looking for help in a question in exercise 17.1 that:

> How many different subgraphs are there in a given graph with V vertices and E edges?

At first I thought the answer should be 2^(E-1) , because basically taking a subset of edges to form a graph (not sure if it is correct let me know).

But then I read an answer on:

> https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3988719/how-many-subgraphs-can-be-formed-from-a-graph-having-e-sides

which made me think that my idea might be wrong, and I cannot find an actual answer to this problem . Any help to this would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there is any simple answer to this question.  Consider:

- if the subgraph has no edges, it can have any choice of the $V$ vertices: $2^V$ possibilities;
- if it has one edge, there are $E$ choices for this edge; the subgraph must have both endpoints of this edge, but there are still $2^{V-2}$ choices among the other vertices;
- if two edges, there are $C(E,2)$ choices, but there may be $2^{V-3}$ or $2^{V-4}$ choices for "extra" vertices, depending on whether the chosen edges have a common endpoint or not;
- three edges may have $3,4,5$ or $6$ endpoints altogether, and I think you can see that this is getting very complicated.

...and just to make it even worse, I have assumed you are talking about a "graph" in the sense that there are no loops or parallel edges.  If this is not the case there are extra difficulties even in the case of one edge.

I think you should check to see whether exercise 17.1 had any further assumptions on the given graph or allowable subgraphs.

Comment: Hey thanks @David , Yes here graphs as in discrete mathematics is one with no loops and parallel edges, now following your idea , I guess if we follow for E edges like 2^V + 2^(V-2) + (2^(V-3) + 2^(V-4) ) + (2^(V-4) + 2^(V-2) + 2^(V-2) ) ... I guess we are getting some kind of series like sum of GPs, I think I will be able to go on forward from here now , but I will still look forward for some more answers if any simpler exists so. Thanks anyways!